# Extract Min and Max Value from the row value delimited by "#"

Tags: python, string, pandas, max, min

I have a Dataframe which contains columns,

```
Col_1    Col_2

'0'         '-33#90#'
'-1#65#'       '0'
'90'        '-22#-44#90#250'
```

I want to get the min and max for the respective column values. I don't have any clue how to get that.

My output should be like,

```
Col_1_min  col_1_max   col_2_min   col_2_max
0           null         -33          90
-1           65           0           null
90          null         -44          250
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop by columns in list with [`Series.str.extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) for get negative and positive integers, reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and convert to floats for numeric. Then get minimal and maximum values with [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) for misisng values if same values:

```
cols = ['Col_1', 'Col_2']
for c in cols:
    df1 = df[c].str.extractall('([-]?\d+)')[0].unstack().astype(float)
    min1 = df1.min(axis=1)
    max1 = df1.max(axis=1)

    df[f'{c}_min'] = min1
    df[f'{c}_max'] = max1.mask(max1==min1)
print (df)
      Col_1             Col_2  Col_1_min  Col_1_max  Col_2_min  Col_2_max
0       '0'         '-33#90#'          0        NaN        -33       90.0
1  '-1#65#'               '0'         -1       65.0          0        NaN
2      '90'  '-22#-44#90#250'         90        NaN        -44      250.0
```

If need remove original columns:

```
cols = ['Col_1', 'Col_2']
for c in cols:
    df1 = df.pop(c).str.extractall('([-]?\d+)')[0].unstack().astype(float)
    min1 = df1.min(axis=1)
    max1 = df1.max(axis=1)
    df[f'{c}_min'] = min1
    df[f'{c}_max'] = max1.mask(max1==min1)
print (df)
   Col_1_min  Col_1_max  Col_2_min  Col_2_max
0          0        NaN        -33       90.0
1         -1       65.0          0        NaN
2         90        NaN        -44      250.0
```

EDIT:

Another solution with split:

```
cols = ['Col_1', 'Col_2']
for c in cols:
    df1 = df.pop(c).str.strip("'").str.split('#', expand=True)
    df1 = df1.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
    min1 = df1.min(axis=1)
    max1 = df1.max(axis=1)
    df[f'{c}_min'] = min1
    df[f'{c}_max'] = max1.mask(max1==min1)
print (df)
   Col_1_min  Col_1_max  Col_2_min  Col_2_max
0        0.0        0.0      -33.0        NaN
1       -1.0        NaN        0.0        0.0
2       90.0       90.0      -44.0        NaN
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196496/discussion-on-answer-by-jezrael-extract-min-and-max-value-from-the-row-value-del).